# JDBC connection and retrieval of info

Tags: java, beginner, mysql, jdbc

If you are wondering why I ask, it is because I have numerous different methods all with very similar code (the only difference in the code in each method is what is between the generate `resultset` comments). I have tried any amount of times to try and shorten this but I am out of ideas. What I have been trying to get is to have the repeating code in the main method (so therefore it won't be repeating), and then to be able to call the `resultSet` methods from here.

```
/**
 * This is the Main Method.
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
// call method resultSet1
resultSet1();
}

/**
 * This Method shows Resultset1.
 */
public static void resultSet1() {
// declare my variables and assign values to them
String url = "jdbc:mysql://lamp.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/mmeaklim01";
Connection connection;

// declare my prepared statement and assign a value to it
PreparedStatement updateSalaries;
String updateSalariesString = "update Staff_Members set salary = ? where idStaff = ?";

// declare two arrays and put values in them
int[] staffSalaries = { 45000, 40000, 35000, 42000, 29000, 29500,
        47000, 34000, 30500, 42000, 44500, 41000, 29500, 29500, 30000,
        34000 };
String[] staffIDs = { "M001", "M002", "M003", "M004", "M005", "M006",
        "M007", "M008", "M009", "M010", "M011", "M012", "M013", "M014",
        "M015", "M016" };

// try catch block to handle exceptions
try {
    // connect to the database
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "mmeaklim01",
            "xxx");

    // start the update
    updateSalaries = connection.prepareStatement(updateSalariesString);

    // declare my variable and assign a value to it
    int length = staffIDs.length;

    // for loop to take the values from my two arrays and use them to
    // update the Staff_Members table
    for (int loop = 0; loop < length; loop++) {
        updateSalaries.setInt(1, staffSalaries[loop]);
        updateSalaries.setString(2, staffIDs[loop]);
        updateSalaries.executeUpdate();
    }

    // generate resultset1
    ResultSet resultSet1 = updateSalaries
            .executeQuery("SELECT name, position, salary FROM Staff_Members");

    // while loop
    System.out.println("Resultset 1\n");
    System.out.println("Name\t\tPosition\tSalary");
    System.out.println("----------\t----------\t----------");
    while (resultSet1.next()) {
        String name = resultSet1.getString("name");
        String position = resultSet1.getString("position");
        int salary = resultSet1.getInt("salary");

        // print out resultset1
        System.out.println(name + "\t" + position + "\t" + salary
                + "\t");
    } // end of resultset1

    // close the update
    updateSalaries.close();

    // close the connection
    connection.close();

    // add a linebreak
    System.out.println();

    // output a message to the user to indicate that the program has
    // executed correctly
    System.out.println("The Method has executed correctly.");
} catch (SQLException sqlException) {
    // catch block
    System.out.println("Error: " + sqlException.getMessage());
}
}
```

And all I want the `resultSet` Methods to have, ideally, would be:

```
    // generate resultset1
    ResultSet resultSet1 = updateSalaries
            .executeQuery("SELECT name, position, salary FROM Staff_Members");

    // while loop
    System.out.println("Resultset 1\n");
    System.out.println("Name\t\tPosition\tSalary");
    System.out.println("----------\t----------\t----------");
    while (resultSet1.next()) {
        String name = resultSet1.getString("name");
        String position = resultSet1.getString("position");
        int salary = resultSet1.getInt("salary");

        // print out resultset1
        System.out.println(name + "\t" + position + "\t" + salary
                + "\t");
    } // end of resultset1
```

I'm sure there is probably an easy way around this but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "mmeaklim01", "xxx...");` please tell us that is *not* your real password... or change it *immediately*.

Comment: No I have made it up.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look as [DBUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) and [JDBC Template](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) (the latter is more popular). It will give you some hints how to organize such code. Usually you want select query to be separate method and to return list of objects - PreparedStatement and ResultRow shouldn't be visible outside. While using JDBC directly it is also easy to leak DB connections, in your code sample `connection.close()` should be inside `finally` block after `catch` section.

Answer (score 1):

**Try-catch**

When you use a try-catch with a resource that you need to close after using it you should use a [try-catch-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). If your class implements `AutoCloseable`, which is the case of [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) you will automatically close without cluttering your code with it.

**Connection String**

You have an hard coded connection here `String url = "jdbc:mysql://lamp.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/mmeaklim01";` which make you code bound to that particular database. I would try to use a properties file to extract this at launch. This will help down the line when you want to change the database without creating a new release.

**Comments**

Comments should be use to tell something unusual about the code, not what the code is doing. When your code is clear and have good name you can drop comments like `// while loop` (and this is a good example since that comment is not 3 statements before having an actual while loop).

**System.out**

I'm always wary about using `System.out` since it's not guaranteed that you'll have it available or it will be convenient to use. I suggest you look at using a logging framework for this task since it take not that much work to setup and will be way useful down the line in a project (even small one).